# Raw data from USB

Tags: visual-c++, hardware, device

I haven't used Visual C++ before, however I'm starting a project that will require me to use it.

I want to get raw data from the USB. Almost every website tells me that I need to write a device driver for it first... Well I know that!

But I want to start simple - with my wireless mouse receiver, which obviously has a driver installed, which works. How can I access the contents which that receiver provides to the computer, using Visual C++?

Comment: If only you were developing on a UNIX based system. This would make things so much easier :-P

Comment: Exactly, but I have to do it in Windows :(

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use WMI ?

Comment: I can basically use anything as long as I can access it through Visual C++ (which will be the used for the user interface).

Comment: You may find the following to be a good start: http://www.wingmanteam.com/usbsnoopy/

Answer (score 0):

This is a great project - a ton of fun too. Perhaps you can find some resources from this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679480/details-on-usb-no-luck-so-far/17679571#17679571). I go into a lot more detail there. But I'll answer a little bit here too.

First off, you definitely don't want to write a driver. The time of writing drivers is mostly behind us. :) At least for what you are trying to do in particular. As I detail in the aforementioned post, we now mostly use HID descriptors to communicate with HID (usb) devices instead of writing drivers. This is awesome because it seriously simplifies the task.

I will highly recommend you or anyone in the same position use the [libusbx](https://github.com/libusbx/libusbx/wiki/Windows-Backend) library. It makes things *very* simple and straightforward in terms of communicating directly with HID devices. Again, see the post for a much more involved answer, but this should do it. Good luck!